# Is it possible to put the array contents into a HTML class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning Javascript and I'm trying to put the contents of the array into a html class.
 I made an array like this: `const terms = ["term1","term2"];`

```
<figure id="8-12" class=" *Here the contents of the array* ">
   <a href="workshopPages/reeks/index.php">
   <img src="media/fotos/gallery/reeks.png" />
   <figcaption>CKV reeks</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is there a way to put the contents of the array into the class?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
const terms = ["term1", "term2"];
let element = document.getElementById('8-12');
element.classList.add(...terms);
```

You can refer to this doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 1):

yes, by using `.classList`

```
const terms = ["term1","term2"];
var cl = document.querySelector('figure').classList;
cl.add.apply(cl, terms);
```

Also you can use `.classList.add(... terms)` as **@alex197** answered, like:

```
const terms = ["term1","term2"];
document.querySelector('figure').classList.add(... terms);
```